# Chrome has no sound, constantly need to reset Windows Audio Service

Tags: google-chrome, audio

Suddenly I have issues with Chrome providing no sound. The only resolution is to reset the service `Windows Audio` and then suddenly I have sound again.

It's even per TAB, which is the weirdest. I can run a tab with something that produces sound, like YouTube or Netflix. Then open up another tab and it doesn't have sound, until I restart the `Windows Audio` service.

I have the exact same issue in an Incognito browser, plugins shouldn't be the ones to cause this.

I have no idea what I changed. It might have to do with [EarTrumpet](https://github.com/File-New-Project/EarTrumpet), although I can't be sure.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with Firefox and I fixed it. 
(My system is Windows 10, and I have stereo-mix. 
I'm not sure if that changes anything.)

Go to sound settings, and then into "App volume and device preferences". 
For me, Firefox was for some reason not routed to any output, so I switched it to "Default" and now Firefox actually plays sound; before it didn't even have the icon saying it was making sound in the tab or a volume bar in sound mixer
because Windows literally was not routing its output to anything. 
The option in the dropdown list was just blank for me.

You may need to restart Windows after doing the above.

Comment: Did you have the problem that you had sound on one browser tab and not on another?  Did you have this problem, and fix it, only to have it come back again, repeatedly?   If not, then it’s not clear that you had the same problem.